# Logging "Debug" Level is not working in any project

Tags: logging, visual-studio-code

I am trying to get my .net core debug to console so I changed the default in appsettings app.de.settings
"Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
"Default": "Debug",
"Microsoft": "Warning",
"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
}

When I run through debugger (F5) or dotnet run on command line, I don't get any "dbug" tag as I noticed in different videos and blogs. What I get, in every project I created, only the following,

> info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> Now listening on: http://192.168.1.4:5050 Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Now listening on:
> http://192.168.1.4:5050 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> Now listening on: https://192.168.1.4:5051 Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Now listening on:
> https://192.168.1.4:5051 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Application started. Press
> Ctrl+C to shut down. info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> Hosting environment: Development Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Hosting environment: Development info:
> Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> Content root path: C:\Projects\dotNetCore-2019\Https-TestCerSalam7\HttpsAPI
> Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Content root path:
> C:\Projects\dotNetCore-2019\Https-TestCerSalam7\HttpsAPI

Even when I do

```
_logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "some text");
```

I get nothing logged/debugged

Of course I have already added the following in program.cs

```
.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);

                    logging.AddConsole();
                    logging.AddDebug();
                })
```

in a controller, using "dotnet run" outputs nothing to console I get get nothing written to console, I get 4 lines as follows:

> Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Content root path:
> C:\Projects\dotNetCore-2019\Https-TestCerSalam7\HttpsAPI Loaded
> 'c:\program
> files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.3\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled. Loaded 'c:\program
> files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.3\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled. Loaded 'c:\program
> files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.3\System.Net.Http.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled. Loaded 'c:\program
> files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.3\System.Net.WebSockets.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled.

I googled and searched this site to see if I can disable the option 'Just My Code', I was not successful

Comment: Were you able to achieve that you want?